# How do I wait for a connection to be established?

Tags: linux, networking

I need to wait until a target host is up and running and accepting connections on a specific port.

I want to use this as a part of the `ssh -o ProxyCommand` command to wait until the target host has booted and sshd is started before nc finally connects to it.

How can I do this in Linux?

Comment: You can use `autossh` for this.

Comment: @Jakuje, Using autossh means to repeatedly call ssh and repeatedly produce "connection refused" messages oder timeouts. My point was to wait until the port is open and then doing only one then successful call of ssh while not cluttering the terminal.
By the way, do you think a linux command line tool is a "product or service" ? I don't think so.
Instead I think asking for a command line recommendation does perfectly fit this forum's topic of "Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users".

Comment: When your question starts with "is there a tool", it is considered as a software recommendation topic, which should go here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ . People on other sites are pretty strict about this. Sofware/tool recommendations are usually biased and lead to many opinions. If your question would be arranged in the way "how to do this in Linux, I tried this and it didn't work", it is pretty fine here, AFAIK

Comment: @Juergen Question edited and voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nmap for that. The following command will try to establish a TCP connection to the 22 port (SSH) and return the following when successful:

```
$ nmap -sT -p 22 <host>
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-06-02 12:40 CEST
Nmap scan report for <host> (<ip>)
Host is up (0.00078s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
```

When the host doesn't respond you get the following:

```
$ nmap -sT -p 22 <host>

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-06-02 12:40 CEST
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 1.04 seconds
```

You may also want to append the following options to avoid waiting too much while the host is not responding:

```
$ nmap -sT -p 22 <host> --max-retries 1 --host-timeout 1
```

If you put this command in a script with a while loop and a sleep timer, you can get the expected result. Something like this:

```
while true
do
  nmap -sT -p 22 <host> --max-retries 1 --host-timeout 1 | grep open > /dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "Your host is ready"
    exit 0
  fi
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: This seems worse than using `nc -w1 -z host 22` in a shell loop, because it needs grep in addition to the shell. The purpose of my question was to get rid of the shell loop and to replace it with a simpler tool to wait for the port to become open in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect within a loop:

```
COUNT=0; 
until ssh $user@$ip || [ $COUNT -eq 10 ]; do sleep 1; (( COUNT++ )); done
```

The loop will end after 10 attempts, or once ssh connection was established.